# Is it possible to use the ${shortdate} in the internalLogFile?

Tags: nlog

Is it possible to use the `${shortdate}` in the `internalLogFile`?

```
<nlog internalLogFile="C:\Logs\${shortdate}_nlog.log"
    <targets>
        <target name="logfile"
                fileName="C:/logs/${shortdate}_dev.log"
        </target>
```

I'm getting the expected dated logfile, but the internal log file is named ... 
`${shortdate}_nlog.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  No.

Longer answer: The internal logger file name is just a string.  It's read in during initialization and the `XmlLoggingConfiguration` class ensures that the directory exists whereas (for example) the `FileTarget` uses a `Layout` for fileName that converts the value provided using `LayoutRenderers`.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/581#issuecomment-74923718

My understanding from reading their comments is that the internal logging should be simple, stable, and used sparingly. Typically you are only supposed to turn it on when trying to figure out whats going wrong with your setup.

You can still dynamically name your internal log file based on the date time if you want. However it won't have the same rollover effect a target file would. It would essentially have a different datetime whenever you initialized your logger I think.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;                
NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = @"C:\CustomLogs\NLog_Internal\internal_NLogs" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
```