# Nlog config layout renderer {shortdate} doesn't change when publishing

Tags: transform, config, nlog, renderer

Within my Framework 4.6.1 project, I have a separate nlog config.  I run a transform on this separate config during publishing.  I added a line within my publish profile to run this transform.  Here's the code that does this, which is added just before the closing node of the Project:

```
<Target Name="NLogTransform" AfterTargets="PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeploy">
<Message Text="NLog file transform according to NLog.MyConfigIsCoolerThanYours.Staging.config" Importance="high" />
<TransformXml Source="NLog.config" Transform="NLog.MyConfigIsCoolerThanYours.Staging.config" Destination="$(_PackageTempDir)\NLog.config" />
```

Here's the first node of my *NLog.MyConfigIsCoolerThanYours.Staging.config* where I am attempting to dynamically change the internalLogFile filename:

```
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  internalLogFile="L:\Logging\SuperCoolLocation\staging\internal\nlog-internal-${shortdate}.log"
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(internalLogFile)" >
```

The transform doesn't throw an error, but the layout renderer doesn't actually render the shortdate.  Well, it literally adds the *${shortdate}* to the file name, see below:

[image: wrong layout rendered value]

Any thoughts on how to fix this so the actual date is displayed?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: I looked more closely at my config and thought I was missing a Locator reference i.e ( xdt:Locator="Match(name)").  This makes sense as your transform needs to find the node that needs to be replaced or updated, right?  I needed to add a NAME attribute to the main NLog.config node, but unfortunately this didn't fix anything.

Comment: InternalLogFile is for debuging, why do you want to turn it on?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062182/is-it-possible-to-use-the-shortdate-in-the-internallogfile

Comment: I guess I never looked at it that way, thanks for the clarification and the included link.  +1 to you!